# LineRenderer sorting order - lines always in front of everything

Tags: unity, draw-order, lines

I have 3 cameras and 3 canvases.

1. Back Camera: depth = -5, Back Canvas: Sorting layer - BackLayer,
2. Camera: depth = 0, Middle Canvas: Sorting layer - MiddleLayer,
3. Camera: depth = 10, Front Canvas: Sorting layer - FrontLayer,

Orders in canvases are also set (for `SpriteRenderers`, images, ui etc.)

*Back* is for a background image and stars, *middle* for mountains and *front* for the UI. Everything is working perfectly with one exception:

**No matter where I draw lines with a `LineRenderer` - they're always at the front of everything (each canvas).**

The one situation where the line moves deeper is when I set it's points Z to some huge values like 30000 and then - they're just behind everything.

My goal is to place these lines along with the background image and stars on the BackLayer or BackCanvas.

What I've already tried:

- Setting `LineRenderer` sorting layer and it's order from the code. I read somewhere on Unity forums that lineRenderer has to have a special material for this to work but I tried most of them - not working.
- I also tried setting their positions manually, from the inspector, from the code, incrementally in the `Update()` method - they're always in front or complately hidden (with huge numbers mentioned above).
- I tried assigning them to different canvases (back, middle, front) as children  didn't work too.

On Unity forums I also read a post which says that we shouldn't use sorting layers with linerenderer and use only Z positions.

If someone has any experience with this, I would be grateful. I really have no idea if I'm doing something wrong or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - `SpriteRenderer` and `LineRenderer` don't cooperate, as they say on `Unity` forums.

There are two ways of changing the `LineRenderer`'s draw order:

- By changing the position in the line's material's `Render Queue` to lower:

  [image]
- Creating a complately new layer (normal, not sorting) named for example LineLayer and creating a new camera for it. Set the camera's culling mask to view only this layer and turn it off in other cameras.

I hope that will help someone in the future.