# Unity - Rotating X on camera changes result of ScreenPointToRay completely

Tags: unity

I am using `ScreenPointToRay` to draw a Line along my Mouse drag. My code for getting my mouse position looks like so:

```
public static RaycastHit RaycastScreenPoint(Vector2 mousePosition, LayerMask mask, Camera cam)
{
    var ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.PositiveInfinity, mask))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, Vector3.up, Color.red, 2);
        return hit;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Mouse raycast did not hit anything");
    }
}
```

With my perspective camera at `65, 0, 0`, this works great. However, if I change the rotation of my camera to `90, 0, 0`, the line is drawn outside the camera view, why is this?

I want this line to be drawn the same no matter the camera rotation.

My code for drawing line:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        lr.positionCount = 2;
        startPos = PointerHandler.RaycastScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition, movementMask, cam).point;
        lr.SetPosition(0, startPos);
    }


    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        endPos = PointerHandler.RaycastScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition, movementMask, cam).point;
        lr.SetPosition(1, endPos);
    }

    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        endPos = PointerHandler.RaycastScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition, movementMask, cam).point;
        lr.SetPosition(1, endPos);
    }
}
```

This image is with the camera rotation at `64, 0, 0`. As you can see, the Line is drawn inside the camera view as intended, and follows my mouse:
[image]

This image is with the camera rotation at `90, 0, 0`. I am dragging my mouse in the middle of the game view, and yet for some reason, the line is ending up outside the camera:
[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on what you expect to get and what you actually get? If possible with images. What do you mean exactly with it being drawn outside the camera view? Do you mean that when you click and drag, the line doesn't follow the cursor? Or do you mean that if you rotate the camera after you finished dragging, the line stays on the same world position and doesn't rotate with the camera? Or do you mean something else entirely?

Comment: @troien sure Ill upload some images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think I know what the problem is. At least, this is the only thing I was able to reproduce. What happens is that you are drawing your line on top of or **inside of** the object you are hitting with your raycast. Meaning that when rendering it has to choose which it has to put on top (the line or the plane). And at the rotations of 0, 90, 180, etc. it chooses to draw the plane on top of the line.

To fix this, you could give the line a small offset to make sure the line is in front of the plane, for example, change your raycast method to something like this:

```
public static Vector3 RaycastScreenPoint(Vector2 mousePosition, LayerMask mask, Camera cam)
{
    var ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.PositiveInfinity, mask))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, Vector3.up, Color.red, 2);
        return hit.point - ray.direction * 0.01f;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Mouse raycast did not hit anything");
    }
}
```

Or give the line a material that uses a shader that always draws on top of the material used by the plane.

Comment: Actually changing the soriting layer on the line was enough! Thanks for pointing me right! :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of reputation... but troien is right. Not sure why you downvoted them. Your plane and line are taking up the exact same area in the world. Depending on camera angle and position it will either draw the line first or the plane first. When the plane is drawn first you will not see your line due to depth checks. This is often called [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) when it causes flickering with moving cameras or objects.

You can also [manipulate when the line drawing is queued](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/135062) in rendering but just moving the line to be in front of the plane like troien did is a better idea. If you use a transparent material for the plane it might reorder the draw queue to avoid this problem as well but thats more like wishfull thinking than a solution.

Comment: I didnt downvote anybody :) Thanks for you help!